# Text editor that can wrap text in predefined HTML tags like Notepad++

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, gedit, text-editor, geany

I'm new to Ubuntu and am trying to figure out some things. In Notepad++ it is possible to use WebEdit plugin and define keyboard shortcuts for different HTML tags. E. g. "Ctrl + p" can wrap the text in paragraph tags.

Is there such an option in some of Ubuntu's editors. Gedit seems quite slim without plugins so I have installed Geany which seems more powerful, but I can't find such a plugin.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried Sublime Text editor?

Comment: Looks interesting, but considering this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951280/html-keyboard-shortcuts-in-sublime-text-2 I would have to choose the desired tag each time instead of having separate shortcuts for every tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Bluefish does it (http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html). It's powerful, simple and available in Software Center (old version though). It seems that it isn't very popular or at least talked about on forums (never heard of it before), but it seems as capable as Notepad++. The only problem is that it's quite complicated to change the shortcuts, but the existing ones aren't that bad either.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text, isn't free nor open source.

I recommend that you look at Geany or Eclipse. Geany is a 'basic' IDE. Geany is to Gedit, on ubuntu, as Notepad++ is to Notepad on Windows.

Eclipse, is a full featured and robust IDE. If you're willing to put in the effort to learn how to use it - it can really kick ass and has plugins (perspectives, etc) for practically any programming task you could find yourself facing.

I personally use Geany for one-off text editing and Eclipse for focused project work. While I'm not sure that they specifically have the ability to "wrap" text as you described. I'm certain that both offer code completion in many situations. Snippets, etc.

Comment: Yes, I like Geany for "normal" editing, but can't find a way to wrap text. Bluefish has it, so I'll try to use that for now.

Comment: +1 If you could skip the sublime text rant, please.

Comment: @take2 ist "wrap text" the same as ["warp lines"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310312/how-to-configure-geany-to-break-lines)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Sublime Text for example, multi-plataform and high recommended by professional developers, and to create plugins are very easy.

Comment: But that application have that option by default or not?

Comment: I have checked it now and I should purchase a license to use it, so it's not an option.