# How to configure Geany to wrap lines?

Tags: geany

When coding with Geany, I often have quite long lines. I want them to wrap automatically, so that I don`t have to scroll horizontally to see what I've written.

Answer (score 35):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then <kbd>L</kbd> to toggle line wrapping on or off.

**Line wrapping off**

[image: Line wrapping off]

**Line wrapping on**

[image: Line wrapping on]

Comment: Is there any way to make geany wrap on the long line marker column, rather than at the edge of the doc?

Comment: good, it is easy to toggle! would be better if there was a direct shorcut or even an icon. I use wrapping when reading some text, and no wrap when coding, thx!

Answer (score 23):

Go to `Edit` > `Preferences`. In the Preferences dialog, go to `Editor` > `Features` and then check the first checkbox (the one corresponding to "*Line wrapping*") :

[image]

Comment: I activated that. But my lines are anyway about 4 to 5times my screen wide.

Comment: This did not work for me, so I closed the file and re-opened it, and then it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I also had to activate it in the "Document" menu.

Answer (score 17):

Open the menu `Document` and check `Line Wrapping` which is the top-most entry in the menu.

[image: geany.png]

Comment: This options works, but the `Line wrapping` option in Edit > Preferences > Editor does nothing. Weird.

Comment: This works on UBNTU 16.04 lts, Geany 1.33.

Answer (score 2):

There are **three** related parameters!

- 'Document', 'Line Wrapping' checkbox;
- 'Edit', 'Preferences', 'Editor', 'Features' tab, 'Line breaking column' numeric field;
- 'Edit', 'Preferences', 'Editor', 'Display' tab, 'Long line marker' section, 'Column' numeric field.

In the 'Long line marker' section, you can also set the type of the marker and it's color.

Comment: Just to clarify: if set in 'Edit', 'Preferences', 'Editor', 'Features' tab, 'Line breaking column', then line breaking is automatically enabled on _newly opened documents_. If the document was opened _before_ that option was set, then 'Document', 'Line Wrapping' is the way to go.